# .Net core 3.1 c# Console Application crashing on docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, console-application

I created an application on .Net core 3.1 c#. This is long running application. This application is working fine on windows 10 without docker container but when I run this application on docker container after sometime application crashed and following message appeared.

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'nativeOverlappedPtr')
   at System.Threading.Overlapped.Free(NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlappedPtr)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.Cleanup()
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.Cleanup()
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.Finalize()
```

Even I am using try-catch in my application but still unable to find the reason.

Comment: It looks like a .NET bug. https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/4449

Comment: @HansKilian Is there any solution because I am using .Net core 3.1 not .Net 5?

Comment: If you're on the newest WCF nuget packages and it still fails, someone in the comments on the bug said that the bug went away when they downgraded to version 4.7.

Comment: To me it looks like the bug was fixed in december 2020, so if you update your System.ServiceModel.* packages, I'd expect the error to go away. https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/pull/4451.

Comment: @HansKilian I am using System.ServiceModel.* 4.8 version. If it is fixed then it should work on 4.8 but it is crashing on System.ServiceModel.* 4.8. I need to downgrade this to solve this problem?

Comment: The error is on some versions of 4.8, I think. I'd upgrade to 4.9.0.